# How to prevent duplicated ID in partial views and still reference them in the Javascript code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a shared view that is going to be called for each item in a collection. In this view I want to have a dropdown list that will contain the Id, Text and image url of the information selected item. When an Item is selected I want to show the image in an image tag.
I got to this code

```
            <select id="themes" onchange="javascript:document.getElementById('themePlaceHolder').src=this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-url')">
            <option value="" data-Url="" >Select a theme</option>
            @foreach(Theme theme in Model.Themes) {
            <option value="@theme.Id" data-url="@theme.Url" >@theme.Name</option>
            }
            </select>
            <img id="themePlaceHolder" src="" />
```

This works perfectly when my collection has only one element, but if it has 2 or more, I have issues with the ID used to identify the image tag because it is duplicated.

Is there anyway to generate the ID so it isn't duplicated but still reference it on my onchange element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with jQuery:

Pseudo code:

```
 <select class="themes">
    <option value="" data-Url="" >Select a theme</option>
       @foreach(Theme theme in Model.Themes) {
          <option value="@theme.Id" data-url="@theme.Url" >@theme.Name</option>
       }
 </select>
 <img id="themePlaceHolder" src="" />

$(".themes").change(function(){
  // to get selected text
  $(this + " option:selected").text();

 // to get selected value
 $(this).val();

// Now do what ever you want using this value
});
```